# My children like to fall asleep to music, what product will turn itself off after an hour?

Tags: sleep, sleep-training, music

My children like to fall asleep to music, have you used a helpful product that will timeout after, say 1 hour?

Otherwise, the music plays all night. I'm not sure if that is bad.

Comment: We use a CD player. It stops at the end of the CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some noise all night is often a good thing.  We use off and on a white noise machine that plays soft sounds, like ocean waves or rainforest sounds or similar, and it seems to help my sons stay asleep sometimes.  Soft music probably also falls into that category (though it's not free of course in any event, hopefully it's a fairly low energy using device - rechargeable battery(s) or plug in).

You don't say what you use now, but many devices include a sleep timer option.  TVs, many stereos, etc. have sleep settings.  iPhones/iPod Touches have the option in the timer (see [this article](http://www.cultofmac.com/250508/fall-asleep-to-music-with-your-iphones-hidden-sleep-timer-ios-tips/) for example) to "stop playing"; so set play then set a timer for an hour choosing 'stop playing' as the option.  I suspect Androids do also.  Regular iPods have a sleep setting as well (Extras->Clock).

Also, some sleep aids (like the fluffy turtles and sheep you can commonly find at Walmart type stores, which display some lights on the ceiling and play some music) often are specifically set up to play for a short amount of time; we also have a seahorse that the child can 'hug' to have it play for 5 minutes or so, and can keep hugging to extend it, but when the child falls asleep it will go off (up to) 5 minutes later.  Most baby stores will have various sleep aid products like this; which you choose depends on the child's age largely.

Answer (score 1):

Via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alarm_clock#Clock_radio):

> Some clock radios also have a "sleep" timer, which turns the music from radio on for a set amount of time (usually around one hour). This is useful for people who like to fall asleep with the radio on.

My alarm clock has a button that turns it on for exactly 59 minutes, and I often use it . This is 1990's technology, so I'm not sure if new alarm clocks have the same function -- but it's a low-tech, low-cost solution if there's a good radio station available. (Classical is my personal choice.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old iPhone or iPod you can play any playlist and set a timer I'm the timer app selecting "Stop playing" for the "on timer ends" action. 
This will work even if the device is plugged into a set of speakers.

Answer (score 0):

"Lullaby for babies" 1 or 2 make my 11-months old fall directly to sleep.
His favorite is Sound 3 from "Lullaby for babies" 2.

You can download this from Google Play, it's available for all Android versions. Personally I have an old Android 2.3.1 phone, dedicated just for this.

The time of play is adjustable from 10 minutes to 7 hours.